# é possivel criar um Page View partindo do null?

Tags: android, viewpager

estou implementando um método de leitura estilo livro e gostaria de colocar apenas uma imagem de fundo e na hora que eu der o Scroll lateral vim o valor do outro lado, exatamente como um livro recém aberto.
**A duvida é, existe uma forma de criar um ViewPager partindo do null?**,Já que na nossa utilização basica o ViewPager já vem com algo criado Partindo de uma view carregada com informação,e no meu caso gostaria de colocar só uma imagem ou algo do tipo para dar uma impressão de livro, enquanto viro as paginas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O android explica o [funcionamento aqui](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html), mas como falei vem com valores...

Não coloquei exemplos pois a duvida não é referente a codificação em si mas se existe formas de codificar

Comment: Não consegui entender o que quer dizer com "criar um ViewPager partindo do null".

Comment: partindo de algo sem valor só um fragment com uma imagem atras @ramaral, imagine livro, com uma capa e dentro as paginas, seria assim, uma capa só estando lá, no caso minha imagem, e após os valores se eu tentasse puxar dando o scroll viria os valores... coloquei uma imagem acho que ela explica melhor o que eu quero

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O exemplo que refere na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) é isso mesmo: um exemplo.
Nele é usado apenas um fragment que é usado em todas as páginas.

O que necessita de fazer é:

- criar um fragment para cada uma das páginas que devem ser apresentadas pelo ViewPager.
  O primeiro terá apenas uma imagen, cada um dos outros com os "valores" e, eventualmente, o último(contra-capa) também só com uma imagem.
- implementar o método `getItem()` do *FragmentStatePagerAdapter* de forma a que retorne, para cada uma das páginas, o respectivo fragment.

  ```
  private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
      public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
          super(fm);
      }

      @Override
      public Fragment getItem(int position) {
          switch (position){
              case 0: return new FragmentPage1();
              case 1: return new FragmentPage2();
              case 2: return new FragmentPage3();
              ....
              ....
          }
          throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
          return NUM_PAGES;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: entendi, eu só preciso manter carregado como se fosse o background eu nao necessariamente precisaria criar nulo, eu posso deixar atras e só  fazer a comparação se esse for na posição 0 vai  aqui  ou se for no final o contrario, não necessariamente deixar o fragment vazio é uma ótima solução e bem adaptável